# Use specific array column in the where clause

Tags: postgresql, array, where, postgresql-9.5

Having a function that returns an array and in a query we use the function to return results such as:

```
{"TUNDUMA GOING (BORDER)","ARRIVAL DATE",09/01/2016,22,"AT CHECKPOINT"}
{"TUNDUMA RETURN (BORDER)","DEPARTURE DATE",29/01/2016,2,"ON THE ROAD"}
```

How can we add a `WHERE` clause that will filter by the 5th column of the array searching for the `ON THE ROAD` values only?

Is there a way to reference `array[4]`?

Tried with

```
where trip_status(tlid) <@ array['AT CHECKPOINT']::varchar
```

with `trip_status()` being the function that returns the array but am getting the following error:

> ```
> Query failed: ERROR: operator does not exist: character varying[] <@ character varying 
> LINE 6: ...ere trip_closed(tlid)=false and trip_status(tlid) <@ array[ ... ^ 
> HINT: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
> ```

Does something like `where trip_status(tlid)[4] = 'AT CHECKPOINT'` exist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You put the cast outside the array constructor - use `::varchar[]` instead.  The current query will return you the array literal (which is of type `varchar`) instead of an actual array - see the example [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/5900).

But overall, if you only need the output as an array downstream, it would make your life easier if you returned proper columns upstream - easier to use those in a `WHERE` clause, for example.  Then construct your array directly before returning it to whatever that needs it.